# Scrapy ignores url because it is too long (over 2083 characters)

Tags: url, scrapy

I am using scrapy but I get the following error for some of the url's

[scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength] DEBUG: Ignoring link (url length > 2083):

When I copy and paste this long url in the browser I get the page, no problem.

Is there a way to force scrapy not to ignore those long url's

Many thanks

Comment: Take a look at [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). As mentioned in the link, you should avoid writing "thank you" comments, as they tend to be removed.

Answer (score 2):

In your `settings.py` file assign a larger value for `URLLENGTH_LIMIT` variable e.g.
`URLLENGTH_LIMIT=5000`