# scrapy pagination not workint on scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, pagination

Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue? I would like to go to the bottom of the pages, but I can only get to the first one. Maybe I made some silly mistake, but I couldn't identify it yet.

```
import scrapy
import json
from scrapy.exceptions import CloseSpider
 
 
class ImoveisSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'imoveis'
    
    def start_requests(self):

        yield scrapy.Request(
            url = 'https://glue-api.zapimoveis.com.br/v2/listings?0=U&1=n&2=i&3=t&4=T&5=y&6=p&7=e&8=_&9=N&10=O&11=N&12=E&categoryPage=RESULT&business=SALE&listingType=USED&parentId=null&size=24&from=24&page=1&includeFields=search(result(listings(listing(displayAddressType,amenities,usableAreas,constructionStatus,listingType,description,title,createdAt,floors,unitTypes,nonActivationReason,providerId,propertyType,unitSubTypes,unitsOnTheFloor,legacyId,id,portal,unitFloor,parkingSpaces,updatedAt,address,suites,publicationType,externalId,bathrooms,usageTypes,totalAreas,advertiserId,advertiserContact,whatsappNumber,bedrooms,acceptExchange,pricingInfos,showPrice,resale,buildings,capacityLimit,status),account(id,name,logoUrl,licenseNumber,showAddress,legacyVivarealId,legacyZapId,minisite),medias,accountLink,link)),totalCount),expansion(search(result(listings(listing(displayAddressType,amenities,usableAreas,constructionStatus,listingType,description,title,createdAt,floors,unitTypes,nonActivationReason,providerId,propertyType,unitSubTypes,unitsOnTheFloor,legacyId,id,portal,unitFloor,parkingSpaces,updatedAt,address,suites,publicationType,externalId,bathrooms,usageTypes,totalAreas,advertiserId,advertiserContact,whatsappNumber,bedrooms,acceptExchange,pricingInfos,showPrice,resale,buildings,capacityLimit,status),account(id,name,logoUrl,licenseNumber,showAddress,legacyVivarealId,legacyZapId,minisite),medias,accountLink,link)),totalCount)),nearby(search(result(listings(listing(displayAddressType,amenities,usableAreas,constructionStatus,listingType,description,title,createdAt,floors,unitTypes,nonActivationReason,providerId,propertyType,unitSubTypes,unitsOnTheFloor,legacyId,id,portal,unitFloor,parkingSpaces,updatedAt,address,suites,publicationType,externalId,bathrooms,usageTypes,totalAreas,advertiserId,advertiserContact,whatsappNumber,bedrooms,acceptExchange,pricingInfos,showPrice,resale,buildings,capacityLimit,status),account(id,name,logoUrl,licenseNumber,showAddress,legacyVivarealId,legacyZapId,minisite),medias,accountLink,link)),totalCount)),page,fullUriFragments,developments(search(result(listings(listing(displayAddressType,amenities,usableAreas,constructionStatus,listingType,description,title,createdAt,floors,unitTypes,nonActivationReason,providerId,propertyType,unitSubTypes,unitsOnTheFloor,legacyId,id,portal,unitFloor,parkingSpaces,updatedAt,address,suites,publicationType,externalId,bathrooms,usageTypes,totalAreas,advertiserId,advertiserContact,whatsappNumber,bedrooms,acceptExchange,pricingInfos,showPrice,resale,buildings,capacityLimit,status),account(id,name,logoUrl,licenseNumber,showAddress,legacyVivarealId,legacyZapId,minisite),medias,accountLink,link)),totalCount)),superPremium(search(result(listings(listing(displayAddressType,amenities,usableAreas,constructionStatus,listingType,description,title,createdAt,floors,unitTypes,nonActivationReason,providerId,propertyType,unitSubTypes,unitsOnTheFloor,legacyId,id,portal,unitFloor,parkingSpaces,updatedAt,address,suites,publicationType,externalId,bathrooms,usageTypes,totalAreas,advertiserId,advertiserContact,whatsappNumber,bedrooms,acceptExchange,pricingInfos,showPrice,resale,buildings,capacityLimit,status),account(id,name,logoUrl,licenseNumber,showAddress,legacyVivarealId,legacyZapId,minisite),medias,accountLink,link)),totalCount)),owners(search(result(listings(listing(displayAddressType,amenities,usableAreas,constructionStatus,listingType,description,title,createdAt,floors,unitTypes,nonActivationReason,providerId,propertyType,unitSubTypes,unitsOnTheFloor,legacyId,id,portal,unitFloor,parkingSpaces,updatedAt,address,suites,publicationType,externalId,bathrooms,usageTypes,totalAreas,advertiserId,advertiserContact,whatsappNumber,bedrooms,acceptExchange,pricingInfos,showPrice,resale,buildings,capacityLimit,status),account(id,name,logoUrl,licenseNumber,showAddress,legacyVivarealId,legacyZapId,minisite),medias,accountLink,link)),totalCount))&cityWiseStreet=1&developmentsSize=3&superPremiumSize=3&addressCountry=&addressState=&addressCity=&addressZone=&addressNeighborhood=&addressStreet=&addressAccounts=&addressType=&addressLocationId=&addressPointLat=&addressPointLon=&__zt=ama:b',
            headers = {
                'x-domain': 'www.zapimoveis.com.br'
            },
            callback=self.parse            
        )
    page = 1

    def parse(self, response):

        if len(json.loads(response.body)) == 0:
            raise CloseSpider('No more products to scrape...')  


        resp = json.loads(response.body)
        listings = resp.get('search').get('result').get('listings')
        for info in listings:
            yield {
                'link': info.get('link').get('href'),
                'city': info.get('link').get('data').get('city')
            }

        self.page += 1
        yield scrapy.Request(
            url=f'https://glue-api.zapimoveis.com.br/v2/listings?0=U&1=n&2=i&3=t&4=T&5=y&6=p&7=e&8=_&9=N&10=O&11=N&12=E&categoryPage=RESULT&business=SALE&listingType=USED&parentId=null&size=24&from=24&page={self.page}&includeFields=search(result(listings(listing(displayAddressType,amenities,usableAreas,constructionStatus,listingType,description,title,createdAt,floors,unitTypes,nonActivationReason,providerId,propertyType,unitSubTypes,unitsOnTheFloor,legacyId,id,portal,unitFloor,parkingSpaces,updatedAt,address,suites,publicationType,externalId,bathrooms,usageTypes,totalAreas,advertiserId,advertiserContact,whatsappNumber,bedrooms,acceptExchange,pricingInfos,showPrice,resale,buildings,capacityLimit,status),account(id,name,logoUrl,licenseNumber,showAddress,legacyVivarealId,legacyZapId,minisite),medias,accountLink,link)),totalCount),expansion(search(result(listings(listing(displayAddressType,amenities,usableAreas,constructionStatus,listingType,description,title,createdAt,floors,unitTypes,nonActivationReason,providerId,propertyType,unitSubTypes,unitsOnTheFloor,legacyId,id,portal,unitFloor,parkingSpaces,updatedAt,address,suites,publicationType,externalId,bathrooms,usageTypes,totalAreas,advertiserId,advertiserContact,whatsappNumber,bedrooms,acceptExchange,pricingInfos,showPrice,resale,buildings,capacityLimit,status),account(id,name,logoUrl,licenseNumber,showAddress,legacyVivarealId,legacyZapId,minisite),medias,accountLink,link)),totalCount)),nearby(search(result(listings(listing(displayAddressType,amenities,usableAreas,constructionStatus,listingType,description,title,createdAt,floors,unitTypes,nonActivationReason,providerId,propertyType,unitSubTypes,unitsOnTheFloor,legacyId,id,portal,unitFloor,parkingSpaces,updatedAt,address,suites,publicationType,externalId,bathrooms,usageTypes,totalAreas,advertiserId,advertiserContact,whatsappNumber,bedrooms,acceptExchange,pricingInfos,showPrice,resale,buildings,capacityLimit,status),account(id,name,logoUrl,licenseNumber,showAddress,legacyVivarealId,legacyZapId,minisite),medias,accountLink,link)),totalCount)),page,fullUriFragments,developments(search(result(listings(listing(displayAddressType,amenities,usableAreas,constructionStatus,listingType,description,title,createdAt,floors,unitTypes,nonActivationReason,providerId,propertyType,unitSubTypes,unitsOnTheFloor,legacyId,id,portal,unitFloor,parkingSpaces,updatedAt,address,suites,publicationType,externalId,bathrooms,usageTypes,totalAreas,advertiserId,advertiserContact,whatsappNumber,bedrooms,acceptExchange,pricingInfos,showPrice,resale,buildings,capacityLimit,status),account(id,name,logoUrl,licenseNumber,showAddress,legacyVivarealId,legacyZapId,minisite),medias,accountLink,link)),totalCount)),superPremium(search(result(listings(listing(displayAddressType,amenities,usableAreas,constructionStatus,listingType,description,title,createdAt,floors,unitTypes,nonActivationReason,providerId,propertyType,unitSubTypes,unitsOnTheFloor,legacyId,id,portal,unitFloor,parkingSpaces,updatedAt,address,suites,publicationType,externalId,bathrooms,usageTypes,totalAreas,advertiserId,advertiserContact,whatsappNumber,bedrooms,acceptExchange,pricingInfos,showPrice,resale,buildings,capacityLimit,status),account(id,name,logoUrl,licenseNumber,showAddress,legacyVivarealId,legacyZapId,minisite),medias,accountLink,link)),totalCount)),owners(search(result(listings(listing(displayAddressType,amenities,usableAreas,constructionStatus,listingType,description,title,createdAt,floors,unitTypes,nonActivationReason,providerId,propertyType,unitSubTypes,unitsOnTheFloor,legacyId,id,portal,unitFloor,parkingSpaces,updatedAt,address,suites,publicationType,externalId,bathrooms,usageTypes,totalAreas,advertiserId,advertiserContact,whatsappNumber,bedrooms,acceptExchange,pricingInfos,showPrice,resale,buildings,capacityLimit,status),account(id,name,logoUrl,licenseNumber,showAddress,legacyVivarealId,legacyZapId,minisite),medias,accountLink,link)),totalCount))&cityWiseStreet=1&developmentsSize=3&superPremiumSize=3&addressCountry=&addressState=&addressCity=&addressZone=&addressNeighborhood=&addressStreet=&addressAccounts=&addressType=&addressLocationId=&addressPointLat=&addressPointLon=&__zt=ama:b',
            headers = {
                'x-domain': 'www.zapimoveis.com.br'
            },            
            callback=self.parse
        )
```

Comment: You forgot to share the starting URL of the site and the steps to populate the required data.

Comment: Give [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70202385/9189799) a go.

Comment: @SIM Hello I don't know if I understood what you meant.  Can you explain better?

Comment: When I executed your script exactly how it is, I got this error `Ignoring link (url length > 2083)`. However, complying with the linked solution seemed to have fixed the issue.

Comment: Just add `custom_settings = {"URLLENGTH_LIMIT": 0}` as a class attribute of your spider class